# Get BelongsTo relation field with joined data in laravel nova v.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I use laravel nova version 3.

I have a `OrderItem` model that related to a `vendor` through `productVariation` and `product_vendor`. So I define relationship as like as this in `OrderItem` model that returns a joined relationship:

```
public function vendor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductVariation::class)
        ->join('product_vendor', 'product_variation.product_vendor_id', '=', 'product_vendor.id')
        ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'product_vendor.user_id');
}
```

in `OrederItemNovaResource` I defined a `BelongsTo` field like this:

```
BelongsTo::make(__('Vendor'), 'vendor', \App\Nova\VendorNovaResource::class)
```

also I check:

```
BelongsTo::make(__('Vendor'), 'vendor', \App\Admin\ProductVariationNovaResource::class)
```

But they don't returns joined data. How Can I receive correct relationship data from model instead of Nova resources fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,  this case will be handled by belongs-to-through relation that nova doesn't support currently. as other people have same problem with that, there is a [Github package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through) that you can use to make your belongsTo relation with multiple tables